# Is it possible in JavaFX to modify the dependencies of a binding after it's created?

Tags: java, javafx, properties

My question arose when implementing some sorts of graph visualization with JavaFX. There are 2 classes called `Vertex` and `Edge`, with each edge connecting 2 (possibly the same) vertices. Every vertex that has self-loops (edges having the same start and end vertices) stores a `DoubleProperty` for the preferred angle of its self-loops. This angle is computed from the the positions of this vertex and all its neighbors. However, as the graph is constructed dynamically, neighbors of a vertex may change, resulting in a dynamic list of dependencies, so I have to modify the dependendies of the `DoubleBinding` to which the angle is bound.

However, the `getDependencies` method in the `DoubleBinding` created by `Bindings.createDoubleBinding` only returns an immutable copy:

```java
@Override
public ObservableList<?> getDependencies() {
    return  ((dependencies == null) || (dependencies.length == 0))?
                FXCollections.emptyObservableList()
            : (dependencies.length == 1)?
                FXCollections.singletonObservableList(dependencies[0])
            : new ImmutableObservableList<Observable>(dependencies);
}
```

And although the `DoubleBinding` class has an `bind` method that seems to satisfy my need, it is protected:

```java
protected final void bind(Observable... dependencies) {
    if ((dependencies != null) && (dependencies.length > 0)) {
        if (observer == null) {
            observer = new BindingHelperObserver(this);
        }
        for (final Observable dep : dependencies) {
            dep.addListener(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

So is there any way that I can modify the dependencies at any time without defining my own `DoubleBinding`, or can I solve my problem without touching the dependencies?

Comment: If you keep the list of neighbors in an `ObservableList`, you can bind your `DoubleProperty` to that list. The binding will be invalidated any time anything is added to or removed from the list. This should essentially avoid the issue (or at least make it clean to solve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind your `DoubleProperty` to an `ObservableList` containing the neighbor nodes. This way the binding will be invalidated if anything is added to or removed from the list. Here's a very quick demo of the idea:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class BindingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<GraphNode> neighbors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        IntegerProperty total = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        total.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> sum(neighbors),
                neighbors
        ));
        total.addListener((obs, oldTotal, newTotal) -> 
                System.out.println("Total = "+newTotal));
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Adding node with value "+i+":");
            neighbors.add(new GraphNode(i));
        }
    }

    private static int sum(ObservableList<GraphNode> nodes) {
        int total = 0 ;
        for (GraphNode node : nodes) {
            total += node.value();
        }
        return total ;
    }

    public static record GraphNode(int value){}
}
```

Output:

```
Adding node with value 1:
Total = 1
Adding node with value 2:
Total = 3
Adding node with value 3:
Total = 6
Adding node with value 4:
Total = 10
Adding node with value 5:
Total = 15
```

Technically, this doesn't really avoid your "without defining my own binding" requirement, but the [`Bindings.createXXXBinding(...)` API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)) makes it pretty clean to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own implementation of a DoubleBinding that offers the method and behaviour you want.

```
class MuatableDependenciesDoubleBinding extends DoubleBinding {

  private Callable<Double> func;
  private Observable[] dependencies;

  public MuatableDependenciesDoubleBinding (Callable<Double> func, Observable... dependencies) {
    this.func = func;
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
    bind (dependencies);
  }

  @Override 
  protected double computeValue() {
    try {
      return func.call();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Logging.getLogger().warning("Exception while evaluating binding", e);
      return 0.0;
    }
  }

  @Override 
  public void dispose() {
    super.unbind(dependencies);
  }

  @Override
  public ObeservableList<?> getDependencies() {
      return ((dependencies == null) || (dependencies.length == 0)) ? 
        FXCollection.emptyObservableList() : (dependencies.length == 1) ? 
        FXCollections.singeltonObservableList(dependencies[0]) 
        : new ImmutableObservableList<Observable>(dependencies);
  }

  public void updateDependencies(Observable... dependencies) {
    dispose();
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
    bind(dependencies);
  }

}
```

Maybe something like that. (I have not tested the code)

Comment: ups sorry, i didnt see this "without defining my own DoubleBinding"